# Using Promises in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, promise

I have an API call that requires some information to be fetched from MySQL database in order to fulfill the request. The problem is, NodeJS won't wait for query response and I have tried to solve this with Promises. Here is my code:

```
    app.post('/placeOrder', async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.orderInfo);
  var username = decryptAccessToken(req.body.AuthToken);
  console.log(username);
  var firstQuery = await fetchCustomerInfo(username, req.body.orderInfo);
   con.query("INSERT INTO Orders SET ?", firstQuery, function (err, response) {
     if (!err) {
      console.log("Order successfully placed");
      res.send("Order successfully placed");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
   });
 });
 async function fetchCustomerInfo(username, orderInfo) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.query("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone FROM Customers WHERE Email=?", username, function (err, response) {
          var createOrder = {
              FirstName: response.FirstName,
              LastName: response.LastName,
              Address: response.Address,
              Email: response.Email,
              Phone: response.Phone,
              ProductInfoJSON: orderInfo
          }
          console.log(createOrder);
          resolve(createOrder);
      })
  })
}
```

This `fetchCustomerInfo` function will just return Promise object and that will trigger SQL syntax error, because that is not expected database input. What I'm doing wrong? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Update: SQL error has been solved with Murat's answer, but database query still returns undefined. I have made sure that the query works in console when used manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.post('/placeOrder', async function (req, res) {
    var username = decryptAccessToken(req.body.AuthToken);
    console.log(username);
    var firstQuery = await fetchCustomerInfo(username, req.body.orderInfo);
    con.query("INSERT INTO Orders SET ?", firstQuery, function (err, response) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Order successfully placed");
            res.status(200).send("Order successfully placed");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error!");
        }
    });
});
function fetchCustomerInfo(username, orderInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone FROM Customers WHERE Email=?", username, function (err, response) {
            var createOrder = {
                FirstName: response.FirstName,
                LastName: response.LastName,
                Address: response.Address,
                Email: response.Email,
                Phone: response.Phone,
                ProductInfoJSON: orderInfo
            }
            console.log(createOrder);
            resolve(createOrder);
        })
    })
}
```

Edit:

Since I have not had much experience with the MySql library, I did not check the accuracy of the function while writing the answer. However, the way you use `con.query()` is wrong. If you look at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp), this is the right way to use it.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't allow to set "await" keyword in front of function call, states syntax error missing )

Comment: Now it says "await is only valid in async function". I have actually confronted these errors myself today...

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Are you sure you moved the code correctly?

Comment: Now it runs, but response from database is still undefined. I will edit the OP

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I just noticed that you are using con.query() incorrectly. I edited my answer again.